# Angularjs - Modal pop up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to activate my modal but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

.html

```
<div class="column is-narrow topIcons">
                    <div class="photo topIconsHover" ng-click="$ctrl.checked()">
                        <figure class="image is-128x128">
                            <img ng-src="{{a.imageSrc}}">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal-background"></div>
                <div class="modal-content" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">
                    <p class="image is-4by3">
                        <img ng-src="{{a.imageSrc}}">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close"></button>
            </div>
```

.js

```
vm.checked = function() {
        console.log("Here!");
        $('#myModal').modal('is-active');

    };
```

I would like to do it with ng-clik directive to call function which will activate modal. Thanks!

Comment: You do not have an element with id `myModal`

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I was missing id="myModal" and I changed
.js file

.html

```
<div class="modal" **id="myModal"**>
                <div class="modal-background"></div>
                <div class="modal-content" ng-repeat="a in $ctrl.f">
                    <p class="image is-4by3">
                        <img ng-src="{{a.imageSrc}}">
                    </p>
                </div>
                <button class="modal-close"></button>
            </div>
```

to this:

```
vm.checked = function() {
        console.log("Here!");
        $('#myModal').addClass('is-active');

    };
```